# How do I retrieve the visitor's ISP through PHP

Tags: php

I followed this site 
[How do I retrieve the visitor's ISP through PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855967/how-do-i-retrieve-the-visitors-isp-through-php)
to get the ISP data, but it's not working anymore( failed to open stream: HTTP request failed). I also tried to use curt

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.whatismyipaddress.com/ip/132.123.23.23');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") );
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

echo $query;
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Moved Permanently    
The document has moved here.
```

Does anybody know  similar solution?

---

EDITED

The curl solution is working only on my localhost, unfortunately the web-host service doesn't allow that. Does anybody know a solution using file_get_contents?

Comment: Is it not just a 301 redirect to the non-www version? Also note the comment that this violates the [TOS](http://whatismyipaddress.com/terms-of-use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the option

```
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
```

to follow header redirects.

Comment: The curl solution is working only on my localhost, unfortunately the web-host service doesn't allow that. Does anybody know a solution using file_get_contents?

Comment: Depends on the settings enabled on the remote server. check a phpinfo() output and look for allow_url_fopen. If it's on, then you can use file_get_contents on a URL.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Note that this may not work as you expect if the user is behind a NAT firewall.

Comment: The OP wants the ISP, not the IP.

Comment: this is why I'm using this: if ($this->validip($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {   
   return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];   
  }
   
  foreach (explode(",",$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) as $ip) {   
   if ($this->validip(trim($ip))) {    
    return $ip;    
   }   
  }
   
  if ($this->validip($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"])) {   
   return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];   
  } 
  elseif ($this->validip($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {   
   return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];   
  } 
  elseif ($this->validip($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"])) {   
   return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];   
  ...