# IP Info Using PHP

Tags: php, ip

I am looking for full set of IP info like Hostname, reverse dns, IP owner etc.

```
<?php

$ip       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hostname = php_uname('n');
echo "<br>" . $hostname;

echo "<br>" . $ip;


?>


 $hostname = php_uname('n');
```

This is returning my Servers hostname not visitors, hostname.
I also need other info, like Reverse DNS , ISP etc

Are there any Free Apis Available for this lookup?

Solutions i considered, [How do I retrieve the visitor's ISP through PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855967/how-do-i-retrieve-the-visitors-isp-through-php)

Not working now!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Generate IP Details using Php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428830/how-to-generate-ip-details-using-php)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`gethostbyaddr($ip)`](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr).

`php_uname` is like `uname` on the command line => it always uses the system's hostname.

Answer (score 0):

```
$clientIp =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$clientDns = gethostbyaddr($clientIp);
$clientISP = geoip_isp_by_name($clientIp);
```

[geoip_* requires the pecl Geoip extension and a free database from maxmind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.requirements.php)