# Data Scraping using php

Tags: php, ip, whois

Here is my code

```
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $url=file_get_contents("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ip");

    preg_match_all('/<th>(.*?)<\/th><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$url,$output,PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $isp=$output[1][2];

    $city=$output[9][2];

    $state=$output[8][2];

    $zipcode=$output[12][2];

    $country=$output[7][2];

    ?>
    <body>
    <table align="center">
    <tr><td>ISP :</td><td><?php echo $isp;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>City :</td><td><?php echo $city;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>State :</td><td><?php echo $state;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Zipcode :</td><td><?php echo $zipcode;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Country :</td><td><?php echo $country;?></td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

How do I find out the ISP provider of a person viewing a PHP page?

Is it possible to use PHP to track or reveal it?

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fop9.png

**Curl Scrapping**

```
<?php
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
$url='http://www.whatismyipaddress.com/ip/132.123.23.23';
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") );
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);

curl_close($curl_handle);
preg_match_all('/<th>(.*?)<\/th><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$url,$output,PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo $query;
$isp=$output[1][2];

$city=$output[9][2];

$state=$output[8][2];

$zipcode=$output[12][2];

$country=$output[7][2];
?>
<body>
<table align="center">
<tr><td>ISP :</td><td><?php echo $isp;?></td></tr>
<tr><td>City :</td><td><?php echo $city;?></td></tr>
<tr><td>State :</td><td><?php echo $state;?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Zipcode :</td><td><?php echo $zipcode;?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Country :</td><td><?php echo $country;?></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**Error:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLdj0.png

What's is wrong with my code here? Any alternative code , that i can use here.

I am not able to scrape that data as described here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLdj0.png

`P.S.` Please post full code. It would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: Okay a hint, as I am not a rude person: You're `preg_match`ing the wrong string. Look careful in every line and you will see it

Answer (score 1):

[You may not use a script, agent, application or otherwise query this website in an automated fashion without prior written permission.](http://whatismyipaddress.com/terms-of-use)

Comment: Yeah, so. Why not downvote other answers also , this? Assuming i have permission?

Comment: Arguing with a person, is against rules of this QA Site.

Comment: He's not arguing with you, he is just stating the truth. *You are not allowed to do this on this service*. Deal with it.

Comment: Please download these also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7268478/1376289 ,http://stackoverflow.com/a/5428909/1376289  ,  and i see 10 more questions with same answer. Please remove those also.